# Mac app store helper tool Sandboxing

Tags: app-store, code-signing, helper, monomac, appstore-sandbox

My app consist of two executables

- the main app executable
- small console app to process some files, this executable is on Resources folder (no root privileges required)

The thing is that I don't know how to submit this app to appstore, I get the following response from apple

> Invalid Signature - the main app bundle appname at path appname.app is signed but the signature is invalid. The following error(s) were reported from codesign:
>   a sealed resource is missing or invalid
>   In architecture: i386

If I remove helper app, it bypasses this error, but app won't work at all. Anyone knows a good way or example on how to embed a helper app and sign it corectly to appstore??

Apple docs are not clear on this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to sign both main app and helper console tool

Signing .app is documented so I describe you how to codesign the helper.

- Create by hand an entitlements file and add it to helper project (you can copy the one from main app and removing not necessary entitlements keys)
- Create an Info.plist as documented at [Adding an Info.plist to Single-File Tools](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Procedures/Procedures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005929-CH4-SW6) (this step should be not mandatory but if you find the helper crash try to add it)

If main app launches the helper tool you should need to add

```
com.apple.security.inherit
```

this is described in [Enabling App Sandbox Inheritance](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW1)

If main app interacts with helper in some other manner maybe you need XPC communication or if you are lucky it will be sufficient to use [App Group](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW1)

Something like

```
<key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
<array>
    <string>$(TeamIdentifierPrefix)my.package</string>
</array>
```

Take a look at [AppSandboxLoginItemXPCDemo](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/AppSandboxLoginItemXPCDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012292-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

From my experience TeamIdentifierPrefix must be empty on development environment and set to your [team id](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/OSXWorkflowGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html) when you submit to MAS, please handle with care my considerations on TeamIdentifierPrefix (i.e. try yourself)

Comment: I dont have the source of the helper tool, its a console application, what can I do in this case?

Comment: This is a problem, you can sign the binary but ì don't know how to add the plist

Comment: If you do not have source for the helper application but only binary, you can add new Run Script build phase to your main target with the following command
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign "$CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY" -i "<helper_tool_identifier>" --entitlement "$PROJECT_DIR/<path_to_helper_entitlment_file>" "$BUILD_DIR/$CONFIGURATION/$EXECUTABLE_FOLDER_PATH/<helper_filename>"