# Xcode: sandboxing a bundle with auxiliary binaries

Tags: xcode, macos, appstore-sandbox, entitlements, code-signing-entitlements

I have a bundle with a set of auxiliary binaries in folder Resources.
I successfully signed and distributed it.
When I try to publish it to the App Store Xcode complains :

```
App sandbox not enabled. The following executables must include the “com.apple.security.app-sandbox” entitlement with a Boolean value of true in the entitlements property list:
[( "eu.ill.fullprof4mac.pkg/Payload/FullProf4Mac.app/Contents/Resources/FullProf_Suite/Faults",
“eu.ill.fullprof4mac.pkg/Payload/FullProf4Mac.app/Contents/Resources/FullProf_Suite/GLOpSAnn",
“eu.ill.fullprof4mac.pkg/Payload/FullProf4Mac.app/Contents/Resources/FullProf_Suite/Mag_Info”,
“eu.ill.fullprof4mac.pkg/Payload/FullProf4Mac.app/Contents/Resources/FullProf_Suite/Mag_SymmCal", 
….
```

As far as I can see, Xcode's interface only handles the main binary (MacOS folder). I cannot move the auxiliary binaries to that folder.

I manually added to the resource folder an entilement file for each of these binaries but I do not find how to warn Xcode of their presence.
I checked the bundle with "RG App Checker Lite". It only detects the main entitlement file (the binary which is in folder MacOS) which confirms that something is wrong.

All the best

Linus

Comment: Have a look at the accepted answer and all its comments of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13173206/mac-app-store-helper-tool-sandboxing)